# Send text/html file that Android will automatically open in a browser?

Tags: android, web-applications, nfc, android-beam

I'd like to send and trigger opening of an HTML page via NFC/Android Beam in the way that's compatible with stock Android devices (and ideally any NFC-compliant smartphone).

I'd like this to **work off-line**, so I'm trying to send actual HTML payload rather than an HTTP URL.

I've tried sending `data:text/html,…` URL, but unfortunately Android doesn't open these URLs in a browser. It shows it in "New tag collected" app without ability to take any action.

I've tried sending `text/html` MIME payload, but again it shows as unclickable "text/html" entry in "New tag collected" app.

I'm using [this example](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/AndroidBeamDemo/src/com/example/android/beam/Beam.java) with this modification:

```
    @Override
    public NdefMessage createNdefMessage(NfcEvent event) {        
        return new NdefMessage(
                NdefRecord.createMime("text/html", "Hello".getBytes()),
                NdefRecord.createUri("data:text/html,Hello")
        );                  
    }
```

[image: Screenshot]

How can I send text/html file that Android will automatically open in a browser?

Comment: Have you tried just one of those records, rather than both simultaneously?

Comment: Yes, I've tried them individually. Effect is the same. Oddly, when I send image/jpeg this way I also get this crappy tag-detected screen, but Gallery app can send images seamlessly. Is there a special API or message type I should be using?

Comment: Not that I am aware of, though I haven't tried this specific scenario. It's a good idea, though -- I'll have to budget some time to run some tests. Particularly sometime when I'm not on an airplane. :-)

Comment: FWIW, at least on Android 4.4, I cannot get anything to open automatically, if the "new tag collected" piece is what winds up responding to the tag. Even using the URL is insufficient to open up a browser, at least not Chrome. Hence, I don't think this is a problem peculiar to trying to send the data offline.